# What is with "-" in linux command?

Tags: command-line

I am a new Ubuntu user. I just keep seeing "-" in every command line, such

$lsb_release -a

$sudo apt install catkin -y

$rm -v!("filename")
...

this keeps happening, does anybody have any references so I can study them all?

Thanks

Comment: Read the manual page for each command that you are curious about. Google `man <command>`

Comment: The "`-`" character introduces a command line "option". Which options exist and what the options do varies from program to program, but most  programs accept "`-h`" or "`--help`" and provide a short help message. Read `man command`. Some programs treat a lone "`-`" as STDIN

Comment: Options may not require an special indicator (eg. `ps` in BSD doesn't require any as is standard for more BSD/unix commands), so GNU/Linux commands can ignore them too, eg. `ps aux`) however many tools require or encourage the `-` parameter to highlight they're command options.  GNU commands tend to use `--` (to distinguish those options from older unix options) so you'll see them too for some commands; but it depends on command & it's history... ie. read `man` pages as earlier suggested.

Comment: For extra emphasis, each command implements their own options, so you'll want to read the man page for all these individual commands.

Comment: Thanks eveybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are options for commands. For example `-h` is the short form for `--help`,  so if you run `some_command -h` it will print you a short overview/help what this command does and what options it has. Just try it with `apt -h`. If you want even more infos about a command you can run `man some_command` - this will show you the manual page to this command (if it exists).

P.s.: `sudo` in front of a command will run it with "admistrator rights" (as it would be called in windows)

P.p.s: here is a list of free linux books https://itsfoss.com/learn-linux-for-free/